Papa Rudin Theorem $7.15$.
There is the definition of $(D\mu)(x)$:

There is the theorem:
If $\mu$ is a Borel measure on $R^k$ and $\mu \ \bot \ m$, then $$(D\mu)(x) = \infty \ a.e. [\mu]. $$ (Denote this equality by $(1)$.)
There is the proof:
There is a Borel set $S \subset R^k$ with $m(S) = 0 $ and $\mu(R^k - s) = 0 $, and there are open sets $V_j \supset S$ with $m(V_j) \lt 1/j$, for $j = 1,2,3$,...
For $N = 1,2,3,...,$ let $E_N$ be the set of all $x \in S$ to which correspond radii $r_i = r_i(x)$, with $\lim r_i = 0$, such that $$\mu(B(x,r_i)) \lt Nm(B(x,r_i)).$$ ( Denote this inequality by $(2)$.)
Then $(1)$ holds for every $x \in S - \bigcup_{N} E_N$.
Fix $N$ and $j$, for the moment. Every $x \in E_N$ is then the center of a ball $B_x \subset V_j$ that satisfies $(2)$.
I don't understand how do we conclude that Every $x \in E_N$ is then the center of a ball $B_x \subset V_j$ that satisfies $(2)$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Let $N$ and $j$ be fixed integers. By definition, we have that $E_N\subseteq S$, and we know as well that $S\subset V_j$ where $V_j$ is an open set.
By definition of $V_j$ being open, we know that for any $v\in V_j$, there exists a radius $\varepsilon >0$ such that $B(v,\varepsilon)\subset V_j$. In particular, since (by the previous paragraph) $x\in V_j$, there exists a radius $r^*>0$ such that
$$B(x,r^*)\subset V_j. \tag A$$
Furthermore, we know that $x\in E_N$, so there is a sequence of radii $(r_i)_{i\ge1}$ with $\lim_{i\to\infty} r_i=0 $ such that each ball $B(x,r_i)$ satisfies your inequality $(2)$. Since $r_i$ converges to $0$, we know that there exists $i^*\in\mathbb N$ such that $r_i\le r^* $ for all $i\ge i^*$, which implies from $\text{(A)}$ that
$$ B(x,r_i)\subseteq B(x,r^*)\subset V_j\quad\forall\ i\ge i^*,$$
which in particular implies
$$B(x,r_i)\subset V_j\quad\forall\ i\ge i^*.\tag B $$
But since $x\in E_N$, we also know that
$$\mu\big(B(x,r_i)\big)\le Nm\big(B(x,r_i)\big) \quad\forall\ i\ge 1.\tag C$$
Therefore, we conclude from $\text{(B)}$ and $\text{(C)}$ that for any radius $r_i$ with $i\ge i^*$, the ball $B(x,r_i)$ is contained in $V_j$ and satisfies the inequality $(2)$ (which I called $\text{(C)}$ in this answer), as desired.
